# Dynamically change src of a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to dynamically change `src` attribute for `js` file.

```
<script id='mod' src="arts.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

inside `arts.js` I have:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    console.log('arts');
});
```

Inside `banns.js` I have:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    console.log('banns');
});
```

Inside the `main.js` I have:

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', function(){
    $('#mod').attr('src', 'banns.js');
});
```

After a right click I'm expecting the next click to write `banns` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible (without reloading the page)?

Comment: can you please specify the backend programming language because you can do it so easy if you are using something like dotnet razor

Comment: @moathnaji this is a classic php website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `src` of an existing script tag already in the DOM won't do anything. Instead, create *another* script tag, set its `src`, and append it to the DOM.

This won't negate whatever the previous script tag did, though - if you want to disable the click listener added previously, you'll need to do so explicitly:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'banns.js';
```

and, inside `banns.js`, before setting the new click listener:

```
$(document).off('click');
```

Comment: I need to `off` not only `click` but also `contextmenu, drag...` and everything from the previous file.

Comment: If the cleanup you have to do isn't completely trivial, it'd probably be better for the first script tag to expose a function that does that - that way, the script that creates the functionality can also remove the functionality. Eg `function disableArts() { $(document).off('click').off('contextmenu')...` There's no way to completely revert what the other script did automatically without replacing the page, which takes longer and often isn't desirable (like you said).